# Passing mouse events with XSendEvent

Tags: c++, c, x11, xlib, xserver

I am trying to use XSendEvent to pass events from one window to the next. More specifically I want all mouse events to be passed, so XFocusEvent, XButtonEvent and I assume the rest should be handled by X. I have been using xev to detect if the events are being sent and I have been unsuccessful. I'm looking for a good XSendEvent example or explanation. 
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  What didn't work?  Stack Overflow is a place to ask specific questions, not to do it for you.  Even if you haven't tried much, it's good to show you've put effort into it before coming here to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a decent reference:

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/manipulating-event-queue/XNextEvent.html

gets an event for your window and then

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSendEvent.html

takes the same XEvent structure returned from XNextEvent.  Beyond that you just need the handle to the window you want to send it to.